# How to in a simple update set an age

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two rows "birthday" and "age". Actually the row "age" is empty.

How can I with a simple update set my age from the birthday ?

```
create table ex(
  birthday nvarchar(50),
  age int
)

insert into ex values ('02-04-1962',null)


select * from ex


--update ex set age = ....
```

[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0950db131c5b9db753bb519c5598313)

Comment: Never store age. Most people tend to become older each year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date/year of birth instead.

Comment: What you may be looking for instead is a `VIEW` that calculates the age from the date.

Comment: and to help calculating the age, use a `date` field in stead of `nvarchar(50)`

Comment: It's not to be stored
it is to be used immediately

Comment: If you have to have an age column in your table, then do so as a calculated column. You won't be able to `PERSIST` such a column though, so using it in a queries `WHERE` would be a poor choice as no indexes would be able to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to calculate age for some reason, but it is not a good idea to store data that can be calculated, especially if this data will be expired over time, such as in your case.

Putting that aside, this is one way of doing that:

You will need to convert `birthday` from string to date, then use `datediff`

```
update ex set age = datediff(year, cast(birthday as date), getdate())
```

Comment: Someone born on `2000-12-31` is not the age of 1 on `2001-01-01`. And then even if this were the correct logic, what happens tomorrow when someone inevitably has a birthday?

Comment: the birthday is in nvarchar(255) and the format is : 
'DD--MM-YYYY'
'02-04-1962'

Comment: @KeusT fix your design; don't store dates as a `(n)varchar` there are **6** date and time data types to choose from. As for the value `N'02-04-1962'` is that 02 April 1962 or 04 February 1962? How do *you* know? Or, more importantly, how would the SQL Server instance know? What's stopping someone from entering the date `N'12-27-1974'`? Or a nonsense value like `N'02-29-1985'`?

Comment: @KeusT no, this doesn't work great, the logic is wrong... People don't age on the first day of the year.

Comment: Try `SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST('20000901' AS date), GETDATE()) AS Age;` @KeusT . This *incorrectly* gives the age `22`. Someone born on 01 September 2000 doesn't turn 22 until 01 September 2022; they are *not* 22 today.

Comment: @Larnu I doubt that the OP wanted that level of precision and accuracy when asking this question. I guess he is fine with the possibility of an error margin of +1 or -1 years in the age calculation. For a better solution, I would count datediff in Days and divide by 365

Comment: If they wanted a margin of error of <= 365 days then they aren't after age, @Ahmad . The method in that comment also wouldn't work as someone got older; leap years (normally) occur every 4 years.